# Activate screen when hitting enter C#

Tags: c#

I have a login screen and I want to activate it when I press enter in the password textbox.
the problem is that even though it works, when I close the form the app acts like enter is still pressed and the form opens in an endless loop.

here is my code:

```
  private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox2_KeyDown);

        }

 public void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (user == Username[1] && pass == passwords[1])
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login successfull", "Welcome, HR");
                    UpdateDBForm newEmployee = new UpdateDBForm();
                    this.Hide();
                    newEmployee.ShowDialog();  
                    return;

                }
}
```

How tdo I solve this problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: `+=` usually means add to... So whenever your text changes another `KeyEventHandler` is added to `KeyDown` which is not really what you want. Register that on startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the `KeyDown`-EventHandler everytime your text changes:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox2.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox2_KeyDown); // EVIL!
}
```

This means, that the more often you input data into your textbox, the more the eventhandler will be assigned and when you eventually hit enter it will be called as many times.
Assign the eventhandler once, i.e. in your constructor and this should work.

Comment: Not out of the blue right now, but consider this as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

As @bash.d written you are assigning event multiple times, do it once (either by designer or in constructor (after `InitializeComponent` call) or in `Form_Load` event)

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox2.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox2_KeyDown);
}
```

also you've written that you want login after user click enter, so you have to add this `if`:

```
public void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (user == Username[1] && pass == passwords[1])
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login successfull", "Welcome, HR");
            UpdateDBForm newEmployee = new UpdateDBForm();
            this.Hide();
            newEmployee.ShowDialog();
            return;        
        }
    }
}
```